# How to make LinearLayout and Switch occupy equal width spaces using Layout Weights?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have the following android layout markup for the settings page am building for an application I am developing. When I use a Spinner like in the following layout, its parent `LinearLayout` occupies half the width of the device screen and the `Spinner` occupies the other half of the device screen width. The markup is like below

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@android:color/black"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightSum="2"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:layout_margin="4dp">

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAlignment="center"
         android:text="Playback Speed"
         android:textColor="#FFF"
         android:textSize="17dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_gravity="center"/>

      <TextView 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAlignment="center"
         android:text="@string/speed"
         android:textColor="#FFF"
         android:textSize="10dp"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <Spinner
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:id="@+id/speeds"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I expected the parent `LinearLayout` of the `Spinner` to be half the width of the entire device as I told it to have a weight of 1 as it is a child of a parent whose weight sum is 2 and has a `match_parent` width property. But immediately I change the element name from Spinner to Switch then the LinearLayout occupies the whole width, how can I make sure both the `Switch` and the `LinearLayout` share equal widths?

Comment: when using weights, use `0dp` as your dynamic dimension. Or better yet use ConstraintLayout and make it explicit. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if it works. Or did I understand the question wrong?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Playback Speed"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2x"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/speeds"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```